# Checking dynamic Checkboxes on Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a dynamic table full of checkboxes that may or may not be checked. I have written a jquery script that changes the bg color of the table cell it is in whenever a checkbox is modified; however, it's quite buggy and it doesn't always change the BG color instantly.

Any suggestions?

> ```
> var check;
>
> $('[id^=approvalcd]').change(function(){
> if($(this).is(":checked") != check) { 
>      check = $(this).prop("checked");
>      $('.approvalROW'+$(this).prop('id').split('approvalcd')[1]).css('background-color', color);
> }else{
>      $('.approvalROW'+$(this).prop('id').split('approvalcd')[1]).css('background-color', 'inherit');
> }
> });
> ```

HTML:

> ```
> <td class='approvalROW" . $counter . "'>
> <input id='approvalcd" . $counter ."' name='ApprovalCd" . $counter . "' type='checkbox'></td>
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by quite buggy? By using ``.change()`` already checked checkboxes are not affected, it that OK? Please provide some HTML and more JS (is ``color`` defined? Is the given ID from a checkbox, tr or th/td?)

Comment: th/td..

I have multiple rows with the id "approvalROW#" and each checkbox has an id of "approvalcd#" with # being the dynamic amount of rows there are. I'd like to detect change for each and change background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that using classes is more flexible:

```
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
})
.find(':checkbox').trigger('change');
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hkL43/1/

Comment: oh... that's nice. Very clean.

Comment: This is excellent! It works flawlessly! I had to change "this.checked" to "this" to make it work with checkboxes that are checked by default! Thank you!

Comment: See updated answer how you can trigger initial checkboxes change event. Also you can go like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hkL43/2/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, albeit untested:

```
$('table td input[type="checkbox""]').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', this.checked ? 'color' : 'inherit');
});
```

Comment: I previously had " $('[id^=approvalcd]').change(function(){ " to check all the checkboxes with the id "approvalcd#" with # being the dynamic amount of rows in the table. Unfortunately, I've tried working around your script but I can't get it to work. :-(

Comment: Have you considered showing your HTML? Perhaps a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you are finding the table row element.  Use...

```
$(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', color);
```

I don't know your html, but that would likely give more consistent results.